# filtering a find() result in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find

I would like to perform a *find* over a mongodb collection (some *groups* that are identified with their *title* string field) but according to an array of criteria.
The only way I found to do this is:

```
let groupTitles = ['foo', 'bar'];
Groups.find({ "$or": groups.map(title => ({ title })) });
```

I wonder is there is a more elegant solution out there, especially if `groupTitles` becomes a very large array.

Comment: How is your Group schema like? If it's of the structure `{ _id: ObjectId(..), title: "foo"}` for example, then you can use [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) as simply `db.Groups.find({ "title": { "$in": groupTitles } });`

Comment: Seems great. Thanks.